# How to take only specific indexes and map to another indexes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I need to make an api call with particular parameter.

See example below:

`const apiFunc = (someId, anotherId) => apiCall(someId, anotherId) }`

However in an array called `someArr` I get something like `[1, 'someId', 2, 'anotherId', 3, 'anotherId', 4, 'someId']`

I need to use in `apiCall()` if for example `1` (same as `4`) if `'someId'` is next to it, and `2` (same as `3`) if `'anotherId'` is next to it.

How can I properly format this please to achieve desired result?

Thanks

I have tried using `.includes()` but without much success.

Comment: [Chunk the array into tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8495687/1048572), create a `Map` from it, then `apiCall(map.get(1), map.get(3))`.

Comment: Can you post an example please? @Bergi

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you be explicit which separate `apiCall` calls you want to make (with literal arguments provided) for a sample input array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `filter` to extract all values that precede "someId", and another `filter` call to extract all values that precede "anotherId". Then pair them when you make the api calls:

```js
// Mock 
const apiCall = (someId, anotherId) => console.log(someId, anotherId);

const arr = [1, 'someId', 2, 'anotherId', 3, 'anotherId', 4, 'someId'];

// Extract the "someId" values
const someId = arr.filter((val, i) => arr[i+1] == "someId");
// Extract the "otherId" values
const otherId = arr.filter((val, i) => arr[i+1] == "anotherId");
// Iterate the pairs of someId, otherId:
for (let i = 0; i < someId.length; i++) {
    apiCall(someId[i], otherId[i]);
}
```

Comment: Oh that is what the OP wanted? I would never have guessed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple function like this:

```
const getId = (array, number): string | null => {
  const index = array.indexOf(number);

  if (index === -1 || index === array.length - 1) {
    return null;
  }

  return array[index + 1];
};
```

and then use it like so:

```
const id1 = getId(someArr, 1);  // 'someId'
const id2 = getId(someArr, 3);  // 'anotherId'

apiCall(id1, id2);
```

Comment: In my example i can have many of these occurrences.  How can I adjust to that?

I need to map `someId` to what it belongs to and same with `anotherId`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. `getId(someArr, 4)` will return 'someId';

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want to achieve? Just describe input and expected output.